# Execution failed: TypeError: - Following replacement of DocsList with DriveApp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps, google-docs-api

I now understand that my broken script began as a result of the recent depreciation of DocsList. Following instruction I have now replaced all instances of this to DriveApp. However execution still fails, multiple file copies are being made in various folders and emails are not sending. I would really appreciate is someone could help me fix this as this is killing my novice brain!

Here is the execution transcript.

```
[15-04-23 12:57:06:192 BST] FormApp.getActiveForm() [0.234 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:06:491 BST] FormApp.getActiveForm() [0.23 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:06:524 BST] Starting execution
[15-04-23 12:57:06:558 BST] FormResponse.getItemResponses() [0.012 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:06:559 BST] (class).getResponse() [0 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:06:559 BST] (class).getResponse() [0 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:06:559 BST] (class).getResponse() [0 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:06:890 BST] SpreadsheetApp.openById([1pxcz1Xt9_29n2L5kDgJlacHCZ8APlIXiTsPXL5M1zuM]) [0.33 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:07:178 BST] Spreadsheet.getDataRange() [0.286 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:07:269 BST] Range.getValues() [0.09 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:07:270 BST] Range.getLastRow() [0 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:07:270 BST] (class).getResponse() [0 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:07:271 BST] (class).getResponse() [0 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:07:271 BST] (class).getResponse() [0 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:07:271 BST] (class).getResponse() [0 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:07:271 BST] (class).getResponse() [0 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:07:271 BST] (class).getResponse() [0 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:07:272 BST] (class).getResponse() [0 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:07:272 BST] (class).getResponse() [0 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:07:272 BST] (class).getResponse() [0 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:07:513 BST] SpreadsheetApp.openById([1fdOI61__16jFCEDJCvWHtVMu6BhkxS88x5408-JB8oA]) [0.239 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:07:513 BST] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([main]) [0 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:07:690 BST] Sheet.getLastRow() [0.176 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:07:691 BST] Sheet.getRange([475, 1, 1, 7]) [0 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:07:693 BST] Range.setValues([[[23.04.2015 12:57:07, Andrew Davies, Lisa Smith, AWOL, 2015-04-23, 11:30, 20:00]]]) [0.001 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:07:859 BST] CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar() [0.165 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:08:275 BST] Calendar.createEvent([Lisa Smith  AWOL deadline., Thu Apr 23 07:00:00 PDT 2015, Thu Apr 23 07:15:00 PDT 2015, {guests=andrew.davies@uk.webhelp.com,adam.taylor@uk.webhelp.com, sendInvites=true}]) [0.414 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:08:485 BST] DriveApp.getFileById([17i-HIzzNTMeVs8u7gIs_NHDoCDlFWX2y7D6LjnYEjUI]) [0.208 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:11:188 BST] File.makeCopy([AWOL_copy]) [2.702 seconds]
[15-04-23 12:57:11:280 BST] Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot find function removeFromFolder in object AWOL_copy. (line 164, file "utils") [4.646 seconds total runtime]
```

And here is the referenced error code

```
function copy_file(path, file,new_name) {
  var file_copy = file.makeCopy(new_name);
      file_copy.removeFromFolder(DriveApp.getRootFolder());
      file_copy.addToFolder(DriveApp.getFolder(path));
  return file_copy;
}


function create_doc_in_path(path, filename) {
  var doc = DocumentApp.create(filename);
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
  file.removeFromFolder(DriveApp.getRootFolder());
  file.addToFolder(DriveApp.getFolder(path));
  return doc;
}
```

Comment: The apis are not the same. Dont just replace the name Also look at what the new api does in each case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zig Mandel is correct, you need to map each functionality of older api with newer api.[more info of DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)

here is code may work.

```
function copy_file(path,file,new_name) 
{
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(path);
  var file_copy = file.makeCopy(new_name);
  var document = DriveApp.getFileById(file_copy.getId());
  folder.addFile(document);
  return file_copy;
}

function create_doc_in_path(path,filename) 
{
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(path);
  var doc = DocumentApp.create(filename);
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
  folder.addFile(file);
  return doc;
}
```

Comment: [15-04-23 15:18:17:300 BST] DriveApp.getFileById([1zsles2lfermNoYLhXB4dVApJStj_zoslTQfgp-BM4Ng]) [0.118 seconds]
[15-04-23 15:18:17:403 BST] DriveApp.getFolderById([Project/Central       Absence Form Directory]) [0.102 seconds]
[15-04-23 15:18:17:481 BST] Execution failed: No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it. (line 164, file "utils") [1.542 seconds total runtime]

Comment: Thanks Sachin K but now I receive the above error. Any idea?

Comment: when you calling function copy_file(path,file,new_name) what are the parameter you send i.e what is value of path , is it folder id (key) or folder name (string)

Comment: var working_directory ='Project/Central Absence Form Directory';  but the documents being used Absence, Lateness, AWOL, - Final _file_id are identified by their document key.

Comment: in  above solution change DriveApp.getFolderById(path); to DriveApp.getFoldersByName(path);

Comment: [15-04-23 15:54:56:964 BST] Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot find function addFile in object FolderIterator. (line 167, file "utils") [6.029 seconds total runtime]

Comment: Sorry about this! It must be very frustrating working with novices! Error above.

Comment: if your script is not private then can you post full script....if you post i can help

Comment: Thank you! It is large and made up of 4 blocks; main.gs, utils.gs, dsl.gs, processes.gs what and where will I post ?

Comment: post the link in comment

Comment: Form with code is secure to company domain users only so I cant send link? Shall I email code?

Comment: hai Imran Ali, i not got your email, try this one last.....step1: use same above code...step 2: go to your google drive go to Project-> Central Absence Form Directory step 3: copy the id of that directory (yo can get while shring of directory link) step 4: change in your source var working_directory = "<<key you get from step 4>>"  and then run program

Comment: Execution failed: No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it. (line 164, file "utils") [1.622 seconds total runtime] I have emailed you all parts of the code buddy.